# Benchmarking and lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

What is wrong here, is Lazy Evaluation too?

teste.hs

```
module Main where  

import Control.Parallel(par,pseq)  
import Text.Printf  
import Control.Exception  
import System.CPUTime  
import Data.List  
import IO  
import Data.Char  
import Control.DeepSeq  

--Calcula o tempo entre o inicio e o fim de rodagem do programa  
time :: IO t -> IO t  
time a = do  
    start <- getCPUTime  
    v <- a
    end   <- getCPUTime  
    let diff = (fromIntegral (end - start)) / (10^12)  
    printf "Computation time: %0.3f sec\n" (diff :: Double)  
    return v  

learquivo :: FilePath -> IO ([[Int]])  
learquivo s = do   
            conteudo <- readFile s   
            return (read conteudo)   

main :: IO ()  
main = do   
    conteudo <- learquivo "mkList1.txt"   
    mapasort <- return (map sort conteudo)
    time $ mapasort  `seq` return ()
```

> `*Main> main
>
>   Computation time: 0.125 sec`

mkList1.txt is a list of 100 lists of 100 random numbers in each, more or less like this: [[23,45,89,78,89 ...], [4783, 44, 34 ...]...]

I did a test printing mapasort:

- time $ print ("Sort usando map = ", mapasort)

And the computing time increased considerably so I think something is wrong.

`Computation time: 1.188 sec`

Thanks

Comment: You mentioned having trouble installing Criterion.  If you go on freenode (IRC) and join the #haskell channel people there can help you get it installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is due to Haskell's laziness. You're trying to get around the laziness by using `seq`, but since `seq` is "shallow" (i.e. it doesn't traverse the whole structure of the expression - only the "outer" layer), it will force the evaluation of the `map`, but not the evaluation of the `sort`s.

To fix this either use `deepseq` instead of `seq` or, even better, use a library for benchmarking instead of using `getCPUTime`.

Comment: sepp2k, is there any library of benchmarking, which calculates the time equal to getCPUTime? Criteriom tried to install but could not she do it?